# How to store value of sqlcmd query into variable in shell scripting

Tags: shell-script, rhel, sqlserver

I tried to store the value of my sqlcmd query into variable and display the output.
For example

```
cwdusers=$(sqlcmd -S "mydb" -U xxx -P xxxxx -d My_DB -Q "select count(*) from user_table")
echo "Total No of users = $cwdusers"
```

it gives the output as :

```
Total No of users

1440

(1 rows affected)
```

when i run it with `grep -v "rows"` 1 row effected column disappears but not the hyphens. I want the o/p to be stored in variable and display it in website.

Comment: You should probably be addressing this in the `sqlcmd` itself - for example, adding `set nocount on` to the query and adding `-h -1` to suppress the header. See for example [Is there a way to suppress “x rows affected” in SQLCMD from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14331836)

Comment: Faraz I've turned your quote block into a code block. If it's not correct please do [edit] it so that it is.

Comment: Thanks I got the output also by using sed i replaced .